# Registrar with good security, DNS hosting, and DNSSEC and IPv6 resolvers?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, godaddy, domain-registrar

I'm looking to move my domains away from GoDaddy, but I'm having a tough time finding anyone with comparable features at a (even remotely) similar price.

I've looked at the usual suggestions (NameCheap, Gandi.net, etc.), but they all seem to lack many of the GoDaddy feature base.

I'm looking for:

- DNSSEC
- IPv6 Resolvers (dig pdns01.domaincontrol.com AAAA; etc. )
- SSL-Logins by default
- HTTP-only login cookies
- No stupid password restrictions
- Two-factor authentications
- No DNS record limits
- Rough DNS statistics (queries/day, etc.)
- Audit trails

GoDaddy has all of these, except two-factor, for $3/month. See http://www.godaddy.com/domains/dns-hosting.aspx

I can't seem to find *any* other registrar that supports even a few of these.

Is there a registrar that offers comparable features? Or, barring that, a DNS hosting service that offers similar features? (AWS Route53 doesn't offer DNSSEC or IPv6)

Comment: +1 just for wanting to leave godaddy. I moved my domains to Namecheap yesterday.

Comment: Agreed. I'm moving mine away to hover.com. They're very helpful and responsive. Not sure though that they fit all of @semenko's criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't let the name fool you but you should check out [easydns](https://web.easydns.com/) as an option. They may not be as cheap as GoDaddy but they have been around for a long time and they handle some big companies. [Their about page](https://web.easydns.com/About/) says it all. The complete feature list is [here](https://web.easydns.com/feature_list.php). I have never used them personally but I've heard their name come up a few times.

- [Register/Transfer domains](https://web.easydns.com/Bulk_domain_name_transfer.php)
- [IPv6](http://blog2.easydns.org/2011/02/04/easydns-and-ipv6-deployment/)
- [DNSSEC](http://blog2.easydns.org/tag/dnssec/)
- Native Support for Amazon AWS Route53 DNS (GUI and DNS Mirroring)
- I am not sure about HTTP-only login cookies, No stupid password restrictions and Two-factor authentications as they are related to their control panel and frankly I would be surprised if they didn't have these.
- I'm not sure about reporting and such but you should send them an email or give them a call. They have add on features.

I also thought of [UltraDNS](https://www.ultradns.net/) owned by Neustar but I don't think they operate like a regular domain registrar.  I have used UltraDNS before once for an online casino project and they did the job well.

Honestly if you need an extensive DNS package and feature set find a company that does DNS specifically like EasyDNS or UltraDNS and use them for your DNS needs. Then just find the cheapest domain registrar you can find. Or just stick with GoDaddy if they got the right stuff.

**disclaimer** I don't work for any of these companies either so I couldn't care less if you go with them or not. I use godaddy because with the right coupon promo code they are cheap for domain registration and quite frankly I have never needed to call for support. One of these days I'll probably get fed up with Godaddy's fisherprice control panel and annoying sales tactics and switch.

Answer (score 1):

I like [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com) as a DNS host.  They offer IPv6, a very good DNS UI (including API access), and analytics. And they import your DNS settings from your current host.

Comment: They don't support DNSSEC, and the DNS features seem quite limited -- almost as an afterthought to the rest of the platform.

Comment: @semenko They [do support DNSSEC](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006660072-Understanding-and-Configuring-DNSSEC-in-Cloudflare-DNS) now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use easydns if you want DNSSEC, they have no way of putting the DS records in the parent zone which makes their DNSSEC support a bit pointless (It looks like their deployment stalled).

I use gkg.net which does do DNSSEC properly, they don't do 2 factor auth (afaict) tho.

I've not come accross a registrar that does all the things you are looking for, but I'm sure your not the only person looking for all those features!

P.S. I assume you mean "HTTPS-only login cookies", not HTTP only, and IPV6 Nameservers, not Resolvers.

Answer (score -1):

I like siteground.com

Security is awesome, and they are very competent.

Comment: Do they meet every bullet point above?

Answer (score -1):

You should try Tucows but am not sure if they have DNSSEC...but they have a very good domain management system...

Answer (score -2):

Very easy:

http://www.mediatemple.net

GoDaddy is crap. I'm surprised you ended up using them. I don't know if MT has the EXACT same features you're looking for, quite frankly I doubt there will be any other host with identical features to godaddy but you can't lose by going to their site and checking things out.

Comment: There's a pretty detailed list of requirements up top. All you've done is throw out a host you like and not even attempted to address the real issue.

Comment: (mt) is owned by GoDaddy now :(

Answer (score -2):

Piping up to also say, yes, leave GoDaddy. Their customer service is terrible. With them, it does seem that what you pay for is what you get.

Have you looked at [AN Hosting](http://www.anhosting.com/)? I've used them for the past four years. They're reliable, fast, easy to work with, and have great customer service. They are always my first recommendation.

Comment: Your "what you get" comment is odd considering the point is that the asker can't find someone to *match GoDaddy's features*. Can ANHosting do that, or at least even get close? Provide documentation.

Comment: It isn't odd: it's a clarification of the preceding sentence.